# How to publish an angular site scaffold by yeoman to remote site?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I use yoeman scaffold a site and added only one page.

```
cd myapp
yo angular
```

Then added a page. There are two issues.

1. It took several hours to FTP all the 22+K files to a host.
2. The page works on my local PC but got empty page except the header and footer on remote host (http://remotehost.com/myapp/app). I found that the js files in the following script block

```html
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
```

failed on remote host because the files were been found in folder `http://remotehost.com/myapp/app/bower_components` instead of the correct location of `http://remotehost.com/myapp/bower_components`.

What's the good way to ftp publish an angularjs site created using yeoman?